How to read wifi connection info on Ubuntu Server 24.04 with netplan, do i need nmcli?
I'm setting a simple server using an old laptop with ubuntu server 24.04 fresh install (yesterday).
Wifi works nice, but I want to see connection details, if it's using 2.4 or 5GHz and also link speed.
As far as i know, with default netplan there's no way to do that and I need NetworkManager and nmcli to view this info.
I tried to install it but anything I try it ends with "unmanagged"
nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
enx00243230a1da  ethernet  unmanaged  --
lo               loopback  unmanaged  --
wlp1s0           wifi      unmanaged  --

Tried so many things and nothing worked, actually i have uninstalled and purged netowrk manager and nmcli.
How can I get this connection details or install and get to work NetworkManager - nmcli?
Thanks!

Use ip link show, and read man ip ip-link.

@waltinator please tell me what ip link command will show me this information. I have a fairly good understanding of it and can't find it in the manpage.

iwconfig will show you link properties. This can be installed (if not already installed) as part of package iw with sudo apt install iw.
To get details simply run iwconfig which will show bitrate, frequency, BSSID and so forth.
